# compiling openttd with VS2005 - linker errors in freetype

Tags: visual-studio-2005, linker-errors

Well, here's a nice obscure one. I'm trying to compile the latest open transport tycoon source in Visual Studio 2005. (It's a C++ app that uses zlib, dx8 and a few other fairly common libraries).

I get a few linker errors to do with the freetype dependencies:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @FT_Done_Face@4   fontcache.obj   
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @FT_Load_Char@12  fontcache.obj   
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @FT_Init_FreeType@4   fontcache.obj   
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @FT_Select_Charmap@8  fontcache.obj   
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @FT_Set_Charmap@8 fontcache.obj   
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @FT_New_Face@16   fontcache.obj   
Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @FT_Render_Glyph@8    fontcache.obj   
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes@12    fontcache.obj   
Error   9   fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals ..\objs\Win32\Release\\openttd.exe
```

I've downloaded the most recent freetype stable and compiled it (also in VS2005), and put the ft2build.h and freetype include directories into my VS8/VC/include directory, and put the libfreetype2.lib library so compiled into my VS8/VC/lib directory. What could I be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` sign at the start of the mangled function names show that your `fontcache.obj` file is expecting these functions to have the `__fastcall` calling convention, which is unusual as the default calling convention is `__cdecl`. I suspect there's a mismatch somewhere in the compiler settings used to build the libraries and those used to build the application. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks - turns out that the openttd project *was* set to build using fastcall. I first tried switching freetype to fastcall, but it threw a couple of compiler errors - so I switched the openttd project over to cdecl instead and that worked fine.